# How to measure User Interaction time of UI, menu made by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, time, interaction

I want to measure UI interaction time like following.

1. Time between Menu selected and showing result.
2. Time between User typing & showing letters in UI

I think many people suggest me to measure the time between function call & result, but I want to know another way to get the time though UI changes.
Is it possible to check the time for UI changes ?

The tool what I'm developing is made by Javascript and run on Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer:

> **"Javascript is single threaded".**

*So,what does this means:*

> Javascript runs code sequentially.It is not possible to run two
>   different pieces of Javascript code at the same time because it does
>   not support multithreading.

Execution of javascript code is line by line.So execution of multiple lines at same time is not possible(it will be very small though)

A simple solution:

```
check_my_time_first() ;//these will be functions returning the epoch time
check_my_time_after();
```

You just need *console.log,flag variables and epoch time*.

Firstly,the difference will be ultra small.

```
var milliseconds_before = (new Date).getTime();//use this code when user clicks

var milliseconds_after = (new Date).getTime();//use this when result appears.
```

Make use of flag variables to know when some execution has been completed.

Another example:

```
var execution_over=false;
function doSomething(){
console.log("start_time"+milliseconds_before)
//some code to be executed;

execution_over=true

if(execution_over==true){
console.log("time="+milliseconds_after)
   }
}
```

Difference:

```
 var diff=milliseconds_before - milliseconds_after;
```

Place this code smartly and you will see the difference in time.

The important thing is to understand the fundamentals.I hope my answer helped.